# Check if List<List<double>> Contains Specific Value in first postition

Tags: c#, list, nested, contains

I have a `List<List<double>> items` where each inner list contains a pair of doubles, where `[0] == PRICE` and `[1] == QTY`.

I would like to check (`TRUE/FALSE`) if the Lists contain a line with a specific PRICE value. Is there a faster way to do this, other than looping through the whole list with `foreach`, maybe with `LINQ`? or a special type of '`.Contains()`' method that only checks the first value?

```
"items": [
  [
     241.947,
     155.91626
  ],
  [
     241,
     981.1255
  ],
[
     240.744,
     21.1255
  ],
],
```

Comment: can you provide sample json on this

Comment: No matter what method you use, you will have to loop through the list. If you want a fast way to do it then use different data structure, maybe a hashtable.

Comment: Instead of using a List for the pair of doubles why don't you just use a struct or class that contains two properties, Price and Quantity. Or have I misunderstood the question.

Comment: LINQ isn't magic - if you have an unordered collection of elements and you need to see if something is true of some element, you'll iterate the list. You could build a *non* list based data structure to enable faster search, but if the only thing you intend to do with the data is search, you'll spend more time between building a structure for faster searching and searching than a linear search alone would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean, (seeing your example that should be the case) that each inner list contains exactly two values - with the first one being the price and the second one being the quantity, you want something like this:

```
  List<List<double>> items = new List<List<double>>();
  var result = items.Any(innerList => innerList[0] == yourValue);
```

The query returns true if there is any inner list that has it's first value set to your price.

Edit1:

Because you are working with doubles, you may even want to check the values with a small tolerance:

```
  List<List<double>> items = new List<List<double>>();
  var result = items.Any(innerList => Math.Abs(innerList[0] - yourValue) < someReallySmallTolerance);
```

Edit2:
Regarding your performance question, it's unlikely that a linq query will be faster than a simple foreach(or a for loop), but you can easily test it. If you really have to win performance here, you may need a better data structure.

Comment: +1. Lookups are O(1) in a hashset, but there's overheard involved in converting data into a set initially. The lookup code would need either a large data set to be checking against or a serious performance requirement to make the overhead + added complexity worth it.

Comment: @AustinDrenski The size of the data is less important than what he plans to *do* with the data - it takes linear time to build a set from a list, if the only operation you intend to do on the list is a single linear time  operation (e.g. this search) there's no benefit to be gained from building a new collection, regardless. On the other hand, if he needs to do the same operation *multiple* times, there's a clear benefit to creating a data structure that's got a constant time lookup by "price" and "quantity".

Comment: @PrestonGuillot You are correct. I should have phrased that more carefully. The aim was to make a similar point to your (much clearer) comment, but I seem to have written "large data set" instead of "large number of lookups against the data set."

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `Any` and Contains Like the following to perform this checking;

```
List<List<double>> items = new List<List<double>>();

items.Add(new List<double>(){12.5,3.4,4.5,56.7,11.3,10.7});
items.Add(new List<double>(){122.5,123.4,122.7,256.7,411.3,410.7});

double itemToCheck = 1222.7;

if(items.Any(x=>x.Contains(itemToCheck)))
    Console.WriteLine("Item Found");
else            
    Console.WriteLine("Item Not Found");
```

Working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ELbOEe)

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there a way to limit this to the first term in the lists? If a different item has a QTY that is the same as the PRICE i am checking for it would be false positive. My items have precision quantities.

Comment: I dont get the actual requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can go with linq to achieve this without loop .
Like ...

> var itemlist = (From tbl in items where tbl[0] == QTY Select
>   tbl).ToList();

Comment: While this avoids writing a loop, it doesn't avoid executing one. LINQ is pretty, but it's not magic.